# Can't figure out integration by parts mistake in integrating f(x)/f'(x)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Start with $$ \int\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \ dx $$

Let $$  u = \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\ $$ $$ dv=dx $$

Then $$ du = (1-\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2})dx $$ $$ v=x $$

Integrate by parts: $$\begin{align*}
 \int\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \ dx &= x\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\ - \int x (1-\frac{f(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2})dx\\
&= x\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\ - \int x \ dx + \int\frac{xf(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}dx \\
& = x\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\ - \frac{x^2}{2}\ + \int\frac{xf(x)f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2} dx 
\end{align*}$$

Rearrange to get:
$$ \int\frac{f(x)}{(f'(x))^2}((f'(x) - xf''(x)) dx \ = x\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}\ - \frac{x^2}{2}\ $$

I checked an example of this such that $$ f(x) = x^3-2x $$ and this didn't hold. I can't seem to spot the mistake so if anyone can help me spot it, I'd appreciate it. The only explanation I can think of is that the right side is missing a + C, but then C is only a constant and whatever residual it would make up for to make both sides equal will vary for all variations of f(x).

Comment: Yeah of course, you'll get a constant $+C$ on the right hand side of the proposed identity but otherwise there is no problem in what you've written as far as I see it.

Comment: the problem is i plugged f = x^3 - 2x and left side didn't equal right side

Comment: Then you have to check your working, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+f%28x%29%2F%28f%27%28x%29%29%5E2+%28f%27%28x%29+-+xf%27%27%28x%29%29dx), your identity is correct. In fact, plugging in $f(x) =x^3-2x$, the left hand side and right hand side differ by the constant $C=\frac{4}{9}$, which is all right.